# Size in bytes for literals

Tags: c++, visual-c++, byte, literals

```
What is the size (in bytes) for each of the literals '7', 7.0, “7”?
```

I was tasked with this question and to be honest, I have no idea how to find the size of these in bytes. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To figure out the number of bytes, you need to determine which type each one is. There are 3 different types listed.

Comment: Note that the second one could vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use the sizeof operator.

for example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "size of char 6 is " << sizeof('6') << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size of float 6.0 is " << sizeof(6.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size of string 6 is " << sizeof("6") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Floating literals are double unless they have a suffix.

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of teaching you how to fish as opposed to giving you a fish, let's break this down into two parts. First how do we find the types of these literals, [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) is perfect for this problem:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid( '7' ).name() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << typeid( 7.0 ).name() << std::endl ;
    std::cout << typeid( "7" ).name() << std::endl ;
}
```

We are using `clang` and so the output is as follows (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c1bcfd3d87e5f66)*):

```
c
d
A2_c
```

In `Visual Studio` you will get the types directly (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/KMBKJ78079)*)

If we had to [demangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) we would using [c++filt -t](http://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) and we see:

```
char
double
char [2]
```

Now we know out types we can find their sizes using [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof( char)  << std::endl ;
    std::cout << sizeof( double )  << std::endl ;
    std::cout << sizeof( char [2] ) << std::endl ;
}
```

for me the result is:

```
1
8
2
```

Comment: `decltype` is probably better than `typeid`. Also, you can (as you obviously know) just use the literals inside `sizeof`.

Comment: @Rapptz they are tools for exploration, for someone who is just figuring this out just saying use `sizeof` is not giving them much. Of course to really understand it is better to goto to the standard section `2.14 Literals` and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

To be pedantic, in general case literals themselves do not have physical size. It makes little sense to apply the notion of "size in bytes" to something that is not "material", i.e. does not reside in memory. The only exception here is string literal `"7"`, which is an lvalue. Meanwhile, `'7'` and `7.0` are not lvalues.

Anyway, when you apply `sizeof` to a literal value (if that's what you meant by "size in bytes"), the literal is interpreted as a simple expression. And what you get is size of the *type* that expression has. So, `'7'` has type `char` and size 1, `7.0` has type `double` and size `sizeof(double)` (implementation dependent), `"7"` has type `const char[2]` and size 2.

(Note that array-to-pointer conversion is not applied to the immediate operand of `sizeof`, which is why `sizeof "7"` evaluates to array size, not to pointer size.)